# Disabling GPU Compositing for All Chrome and Electron Instances on a Mac

Tags: google-chrome, mac, chromium, electron

I have been experiencing severe performance issues with all Chromium browsers and Electron apps on my Mac for years. I’ve filed a bug report with Chromium and have contributed my findings to other bug reports for similar issues but I need a workaround in the meantime.

I’ve discovered that running Chrome with the `--disable-gpu-compositing` command-line switch fixes this issue almost completely, and in a way that is better than disabling hardware acceleration altogether.

On Mac, however, the only way to run Chrome this way is to run it from the terminal as this option is not available in settings or in `chrome:flags`. This is not ideal as it means I have to maintain shell aliases for several apps (Chrome, Chrome Canary, Edge, VS Code and Slack) and each of them spawns a terminal window with console output.

Ideally, what I would like is a way to globally disable GPU compositing, but keep other aspects of hardware acceleration, for all Chromium and Electron apps on this computer. I think something like this should be achievable by modifying the GPU block list. Is it possible to modify it on a local basis somehow?

Answer (score 0):

add --disable-gpu-compositing
just like

`chromium --disable-gpu-compositing`
or `anyElectronapp --disable-gpu-compositing`

just that simple